# Statistical properties from the projection on Hadamard matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, probability-distributions, compressed-sensing

I am using Hadamard matrix to generate the measurement matrix in compressive sensing for signal acquisition. Consider all the rows except the first row, which consists of all 1's, as a candidate for the measurement matrix. The resulting probability distribution obeys Laplacian distribution with high probability. Is it possible to prove it analytically? It can be also assumed that the signal under consideration varies slowly over time.

Comment: Hi Amit, I think some basic equations and definitions will make the question easier to read and less ambigious. Welcome to MO!